# Find delta-difference between two xml File in marklogic

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

I have a requirement where i need to find difference between two XML file-Updated/Latest File(File1) and previous version(File2).
The Updated XML file may have additional nodes or some nodes may be deleted.
I have to compare this two XML and need to show differences.
I am using deep-equal function two compare two nodes but my current logic works only if File1 has greater or equal nodes than File2.
It is not working if File1 has less nodes than File2.
Kindly help or give me some logic to compare
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your current logic detects nodes that have been added to File1, relative to File2:

```
let $new-nodes := local:diffs($file1, $file2)
```

If you can apply the same logic but reverse the nodes, you'll find those nodes that exist in File2, but not File1, giving you the deleted nodes.

```
let $deleted-nodes := local:diffs($file2, $file1)
```

Adding those together should give you what you need. (This assumes your logic works on in-memory nodes.)